# ios 8 Photos framework - replace photos not working

Tags: ios, photos, ios8

I'm playing around the new iOS 8 Photos framework, trying to edit an existing photo in my library then replacing it but it's not replaced, even if I can see all the success log messages I've set.

Here's my code :

```
UIImage *output = [self.imageView.image appendDateWithLabel:label];
self.imageView.image = output;

// self.info was retrieve by the UIImagePickerController delegate method
NSURL *assetURL = self.info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
PHFetchResult *result = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:@[assetURL] options:nil];
PHAsset *asset = result.firstObject;
if ([asset canPerformEditOperation:PHAssetEditOperationContent])
{
    [asset requestContentEditingInputWithOptions:nil completionHandler:^(PHContentEditingInput *contentEditingInput, NSDictionary *info) {

        PHContentEditingOutput *contentEditingOutput = [[PHContentEditingOutput alloc] initWithContentEditingInput:contentEditingInput];
        NSData *outputData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(output);
        BOOL wrote = [outputData writeToURL:contentEditingOutput.renderedContentURL options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:nil];

        if (wrote)
        {
            [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
                PHAssetChangeRequest *request = [PHAssetChangeRequest changeRequestForAsset:asset];
                request.contentEditingOutput = contentEditingOutput;

            } completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
                // console output : 1
                NSLog(@"success : %@", @(success));
                // console output : nil
                NSLog(@"error : %@", error);
            }];
        }
    }];
}
```

Instead of replacing, I've also tried to create a modified copy. This worked well, I could see the new modified photo in my library.

Someone already faced this issue ?

Comment: How is it that you're not seeing changes? If you're not using `PHPhotoLibrary` to observe changes, you won't be notified of changes in your app, so you won't know when to re-fetch image data. If the changes aren't showing up in the Photos app, something's not working right — the [Photos framework sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/UsingPhotosFramework/Introduction/Intro.html) makes changes that show up in the Photos app, so I'd check your app against that.

Comment: I don't need to observe the changes here, and I don't think it is mandatory to do so actually, there are no mention of such a thing on the documentation. It may be useful when you"re editing an image somewhere in your code then you need to be notified so you can display the modified image (seems its the case on the Photos framework sample code). For the photo editing part, my code is pretty similar to the sample code :/ But I'll give it a try on this since I don't have other leads

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that filling the `adjustementData` property of the `PHContentEditingOutput` object is mandatory in order to edit a photo.

```
PHAdjustmentData *adjustmentData = [[PHAdjustmentData alloc] initWithFormatIdentifier:@"AdjustementDataIdentifier" formatVersion:@"1.0" data:nil]
```

Comment: Can you edit the metadata of an existing image and save it using this too ( without duplicating the image )?

Comment: Really wish this was in the docs, was banging my head for an hour.

Comment: If I want to do a simple replacement of existing picture (and cannot be undo), what to fill the adjustmentData with?

Comment: Just use a basic one like `PHAdjustmentData *adjustmentData = [[PHAdjustmentData alloc] initWithFormatIdentifier:@"AdjustementDataIdentifier" formatVersion:@"1.0" data:nil];`, it should be good

Answer (score 1):

You simply can't use PNG format for output, only JPEG supported...

```
PHContentEditingOutput *contentEditingOutput = [[PHContentEditingOutput alloc] initWithContentEditingInput:contentEditingInput];
/******/
NSData *outputData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(output, 1);
/******/
BOOL wrote = [outputData writeToURL:contentEditingOutput.renderedContentURL options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:nil];
```

Wired, hmm...

Comment: This bug is still in iOS 9 and 10. If you inspect the output url, it always ends with .JPG even for .PNG images that were saved to camera roll.

Comment: It might be not a bug, it designed to be like this. The document of  PHContentEditingOutput.renderedContentURL says: "Read this property to find a URL for writing edited asset content. Then, if editing a photo asset, write the altered photo image to a file in JPEG format at this URL."

Comment: @Johny if this is working by design it's a very poor choice of API. Makes keeping the original quality and and transparency / translucency impossible.